# Not able to receive event notification in SFDC

Tags: docusignapi, apex

I am sending REST request to docusign from Postman, but I am not able to get the eventNotification back to the url i am giving. Please help what I am doing wrong in the request.

```
{
"accountId": "8555983",
"emailSubject": "This request is sent from a Template",
"templateId": "4ce7f605-c2c8-40ab-b95b-7aaa0c765245",
"templateRoles": [{
    "roleName": "Signer1",
    "name": "Prakhar",
    "email": "prakhar@example.com",
    "eventNotification": {

        "url": "[sfdc base url]/services/apexrest/Docusign",
        "loggingEnabled": "true",
        "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
        "useSoapInterface": "false",
        "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
        "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
        "includeDocuments": "true",
        "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
        "includeTimeZone": "true",
        "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
        "includeDocumentFields": "true",
        "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",
        "envelopeEvents": [
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided"
          }
        ]
    },

    "tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [{
                "xPosition": "138",
                "yPosition": "654",
                "documentId": "1",
                "pageNumber": "1"
           }],
        "textTabs": [{
            "tabLabel": "NameOfInstitution",
            "value":"Example",
            "locked": "true",
            "xPosition": "245",
            "yPosition": "310",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1"
        }



        ]
    }
}],
"status": "sent"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `eventNotification` attribute must be at the base level of the request object.

You're placing it within a `templateRoles` object.

Try the following:

```
{
   "accountId": "8555983",
   "emailSubject": "This request is sent from a Template",
   "templateId": "4ce7f605-c2c8-40ab-b95b-7aaa0c765245",
   "templateRoles": [{
       "roleName": "Signer1",
       "name": "Prakhar",
       "email": "prakhar@example.com",      
       "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [{
                "xPosition": "138",
                "yPosition": "654",
                "documentId": "1",
                "pageNumber": "1"
          }],
          "textTabs": [{
            "tabLabel": "NameOfInstitution",
            "value":"Example",
            "locked": "true",
            "xPosition": "245",
            "yPosition": "310",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1"
          }]
       }
   }],
   "status": "sent",
   "eventNotification": {       
        "url": "[sfdc base url]/services/apexrest/Docusign",
        "loggingEnabled": "true",
        "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
        "useSoapInterface": "false",
        "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
        "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
        "includeDocuments": "true",
        "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
        "includeTimeZone": "true",
        "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
        "includeDocumentFields": "true",
        "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",
        "envelopeEvents": [
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided"
          }
        ]
   }  
}
```